# Kivy Python For Android Installation And App Deployment

Tags: android, python, compilation, installation, kivy

So I could finally get a decent output in a shell about Kivy Python-For-Android installation and distro build. The thing is that I cannot seem to get the compass example to work at all. A force close is activated right after running the app.

I'm using the latest toolchain and the old doesn't seems to work... An error about old chain not supported any more.

The thing is that I'm using the latest version of SDK and NDK. The documentation ask for android API 14 but it's not found on the android manager repository. All APIs are present but not API 14 so I use API 17.

The installation script I manage to put together with things out of the current doc to make it work on: Ubuntu 15.10 x64

```
#### Tested On x64 System ####
# Enable Restricted, Universe & Multiverse Repositories
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu$(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"

# Add x86 Packets
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev python2.7 python2.7-dev libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 openjdk-7-jdk unzip ant python-pip cython autoconf libtool

sudo pip install virtualenv

git clone https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
cd python-for-android

python setup.py install

export ANDROIDSDK="/media/$(logname)/EXTSave/android-sdk-linux"
export ANDROIDNDK="/media/$(logname)/EXTSave/android-ndk-r11b"
export ANDROIDAPI=17
export ANDROIDNDKVER=11

# EXTSave is an HDD Partition
python-for-android apk --private /media/$(logname)/EXTSave/compass --requirements=python2 --package=org.pirate.kaizoku --name="Kaizoku" --version=0.1
```

How can I compile an example or something? Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm no professional programmer I forgot/didn't know how to check the logs but after more searching I finally found my error! The program was not not able to import the kivy framework. I forgot to add it in:

```
python-for-android apk --private /media/$(logname)/EXTSave/compass --requirements=python2,sdl,kivy --package=org.pirate.kaizoku --name="Kaizoku" --version=0.1
```

Since the original installation code is working I will make some changes for automation and leave it here for future reference for faster approach to the framework.

For future problems use the logs to check any problems:

```
python-for-android logcat
```